# Most efficient way to delete unique elements from array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++11, duplicates

What is the efficient way to eliminate unique elements from an array in C++?

Array given:

```
9, 8, 4, 9, 21, 3, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 6, 7, 12, 3, 6, 9, 1, 3    // keep duplicates, delete uniques
```

Output:

```
9, 4, 9, 3, 1, 4, 6, 6, 3, 6, 9, 1, 3    // all duplicates
```

Comment: a loop with book-keeping in a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`

Comment: @Jenin  Are you allowed to sort the original array?

Comment: Loop, add the elements to a `std::set`, if the element was already in the set when you try that, add it to a list of duplicates.

Comment: this was asked only yesterday... you should at least try to solve the problem on your own

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, no, original is not allowed to sort

Comment: @Jenin The operation has to be done in place?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, another array can be used. Have you any idea?

Comment: @KarlReid, your idea solves my problem almost, thank you. Is it possible to do faster?

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably do it like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> nums = {9, 8, 4, 9, 21, 3, 1, 4, 6, 2, 
                             5, 6, 7, 12, 3, 6, 9, 1, 3};
    // build histogram
    std::map<int, int> counts;
    for (int i : nums) ++counts[i];
    // copy elements that appear more than once
    std::vector<int> result;
    std::copy_if(nums.begin(), nums.end(),
                 std::back_inserter(result), 
                 [&](int x){ return counts[x] > 1; });
    // print result
    for (int i : result) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
$ g++ test.cc -std=c++11 && ./a.out
9 4 9 3 1 4 6 6 3 6 9 1 3
```

It's two pass and you build a BST. If you feel this is too slow, you can try to build the histogram using a `std::unordered_map`, which has better complexity characteristics regarding insertion and lookups.

You can use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) if you want the duplicates to be removed from the original vector instead of building a another. (This is left as an exercise to the reader.)

Comment: Using `unordered_map` instead of `map` could make it a bit faster

Comment: "I don't think you'll get this significantly faster." Actually, it can be done  using a unorderd_map. Instead of O(n log n), it's O(n). I think that counts as "significantly faster."

Comment: @JimMischel While O(n) is faster than O(n log n) in theory, it's not necessarily _significantly_ faster in practice. (FWIW I removed that section, in favor of adding a note on `std::unordered_map`.)

Comment: And `unordered_map` has `O(n)` operations complexity at average, not in the worst case.

Comment: @DAle: Yes, `unordered_map` has average case complexity of O(n), and worst case complexity of O(n log n). That worst case occurs if the items being inserted all fall into a very small number of buckets. That is, large numbers of hash collisions. Absent purposely generated pathological data, I've never seen such a thing happen in practice.

Comment: @JimMischel, could you please show the single pass algorithm that removes the unique elements? How would you know what elements should be removed in this case `[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]` for example?

Comment: @JimMischel I'm not quite convinced yet. I'd be happy to see your solution to this problem!

Comment: @DAle: See my answer

Answer (score 1):

I would use C++ sets, for their logarithmic complexity (EDIT: as [Scheff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7478597/scheff) said).

This solution has O(n log n) algorithmic complexity:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int nums[] = {9, 8, 4, 9, 21, 3, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 6, 7, 12, 3, 6, 9, 1, 3};
    std::set<int> s;
    std::set<int> dups;

    for (int i = 0; i < 19; ++i)
        if (!s.insert(nums[i]).second)
            dups.insert(nums[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 19; ++i)
        if (dups.find(nums[i]) != dups.end())
            std::cout << " " << nums[i];
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void rmdup(int *array, int length)
{
    int *current , *end = array + length - 1;

    for ( current = array + 1; array < end; array++, current = array + 1 )
    {
        while ( current <= end )
        {
            if ( *current == *array )
            {
                *current = *end--;
            }
            else
            {
                current++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//hope this helps u

Comment: Relative to the assignment the function does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<int> nums = {9, 8, 4, 9, 21, 3, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 6, 7, 12, 3, 6, 9, 1, 3};
    std::set<int> s;
    vector<int> dups;

    for(auto i:nums)
        if (!s.insert(i).second)
            dups.push_back(i);

    for_each(dups.begin(),dups.end(),[](int a){cout<<a<<" ";});
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

There is one pass only.

Comment: One pass, but the output is different from needed